# Validating sign of mean

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

I have a lot of experiments with the following kind of data.

The sample size is $n\geq 1$. For each test $i$ in the sample a cost $c>0$ and a revenue $r_i\geq 0$. The cost $c$ is constant. The revenue $r_i$ assumes a few different values and is must often $0$.

The calculate the mean income as $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n} (r_i-c)$.

The sample size increases over time.

At any given time, I want to determine if the sample size is large enough to determine if the mean income in positive or negative.

Comment: Perhaps by making a confidence interval around the mean income. If both end of the interval is on the same side of 0 on the number line I would have my answer. However, I do not know how to make the confidence interval.

Comment: I think you mean $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n} (r_i-c)$ for *income*? Also, is this time-series data, or data from one point in time? Time series data can be modeled using ARIMA methods to determine if your income has a positive drift. If you don't want to go that route, is there a certain time window after which you will not use data (e.g., is data from 10 years ago relevant?). To determine sample size, you first need to specify what *effect size* is relevant to you. I.e., you want to specify, for example, that you want a 99% chance of detecting a mean absolute income $>|X|$

Comment: Yes, there was a typo in the mean income. Thanks.

New test are added to the sample an unspecified times. I cannot specify some max amount of time I would look back.

I would be happy if I would take the right decision about 95 % of times.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you know the probability that your true average income is zero, positive, and negative in the long run? Without that knowledge, you will not be able be right 95% of times. However, you can set things up so that you will be *conditionally correct*: Are you more concerned with Type I or II errors?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I do not know the probability. Not even in the long run.

I do not know what you mean by _conditionally correct_.

If I should pick between the two, I would call type II errors the worst.

Comment: Conditionally correct means that you know the error rate GIVEN that the true mean income is 0 or GIVEN that the true mean income is X, with |X|>0. These are much easier to quantify, and really the only possible if you don't know the true probability. Also (and I apologize for all the questions) are you assuming your data come from a particular distribution (e.g., Normal) or are you taking a non-parametric/distriubtion free approach?